# Uninitialized char defaulting to @

Tags: c, variables, initialization

So I wrote this function:

```
int getword(char *fmt, int delim, int max, FILE *f)
{
    int c, x = 0;
    while (((c = getc(f)) != EOF) && (c != delim) && (x < max))
            fmt[x++] = c;
    return x;
}
```

Whenever I check the function, there is always an `@` at the end.

```
buf = color 32@
/* segmentation fault */
```

and no matter what I did to change it the variable would always end with `@`. I fixed the problem by initializing the variable:

```
char buf[100] = {0};
```

but ever since I have been wondering why the character was always a `@` if an uninitialized `char` can be anything in its range. Why would it default to `@`?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to zero terminate your string

```
int getword(char *fmt, int delim, int max, FILE *f)
{
    int c, x = 0;
    while (((c = getc(f)) != EOF) && (c != delim) && (x < max))
            fmt[x++] = c;
    fmt[x] = 0;
    return x;
}
```

you are getting an '@' because thats what was left over in memory, almost certainly the shell or loader. And since the shell or loader is the same every time you are getting the same random piece of junk. If you jiggle your program around a bit (add a few extra variables before buff ) you will get a different piece of junk.

Answer (score 1):

Original code lacks clearing `buf[]` and even `char buf[100] = {0};` does not insure null character termination when 100 characters are read.   Else the `printf("buf is %s\n",buf);` attempts to print a potentially invalid string.

Further, on subsequent calls `char buf[100] = {0};` does not re-zero the array.

Better to use `getword(buf,'>',sizeof buf - 1,f);` and have `getword()` append the `'\0'`.

---

> Why would it default to @

It is undefined behavior.  In your case, likely the `buf[]` contained the `'@'`, but anything may have happened.  It did not *default* to `'@'`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from an uninitialized local variable invokes *Undefined Behavior*. The program is free to do anything it wants.

Comment: but UB would result in a random character, wouldn't it? And the variable wasn't completely uninitialized; it was written to by `getword`.

Comment: @ProHackr112 "undefined" doesn't mean "random"